# No wrap on whitespace provides additional space when there is a line break

Tags: html, css

I've been using this aligned list to display recent titles.

You can see an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/01day856/

However, I've noticed that whenever I break a line it will show up as an extra bit of space on the top. So, I changed my `.game` class to appears as this:

```
.game {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I've included the `white-space: nowrap;` and it seemed to fix it, but now my titles don't break the line like they are supposed to.

How can I combat the `white-space: nowrap` and allow my titles to break lines when they extend too far? I tried  adding in  `word-wrap: break-word` and nothing seems to work.

Comment: ok so if you have more tiles it should come down right not outside the white box is this what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple alternative would be to remove `white-space: nowrap`. Since they are `inline-block` level elements, you could add `vertical-align: top` to fix the alignment issues:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzb6fu4t/)

```
.game {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```